# How to download image from firebase database, and load it into image in unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I use Firebase Realtime database to handle some of the UI in my Unity mobile application. I save and retrieve data from my database without any problems. 
The problem comes when i want to load an image from Firebase Storage.
I have saved the URL's and names of the images' on my server, and now i try to Instantiate a prefab. 
This prefab contains a panel with text and an image for each Firebase-child.
The structure of the image i try to load from my database looks like this:

[image]

So in my code I go to the child "Byer", find the first name and add the key as the name of my newly instantiated prefab works fine. But when I try to load the imageURL into the image, I get the trouble - my code looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Byer").ChildAdded += Handle_ChildAdded;


 void Handle_ChildAdded(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Snapshot.Value != null)
        {
            var dict = e.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;


           Transform scrollViewObj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, (downSize * Global.citiesCount) - firstY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
           scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Text").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = e.Snapshot.Key;
               scrollViewObj.name = e.Snapshot.Key;

//HERE I TRY TO LOAD IMAGE FROM URL (This is my problem)
            string data_URL = dict["ImageURL"] as string;
            //Start coroutine to download image
            StartCoroutine(AccessURL(data_URL, scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Image").gameObject.GetComponent<Image>()));

                }
            }

//Function to download (This could might also be my problem)
      IEnumerator AccessURL(string url, Image img)
        {


        //Debug.Log("Accessing texture URL in database");
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {

            yield return www;
            Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            r.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
            img.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
            Debug.Log("Texture URL: " + www.url);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is "the trouble"?

Comment: I get the text, but not the image. I can find the ImageURL, but for some reason it doesn't load into the image'view' in the prefab

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you imported `FirebaseStorage.unitypackage`
- You will need `StorageReference` not `DatabaseReference`

  ```
  Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storageReference = 
     Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.GetReferenceFromUrl("storage_url");

  storageReference.Child("resource_name").GetBytesAsync(1024*1024).
      ContinueWith((System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> task) =>
      {
          if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
          {
              Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
              byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
              Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
              texture.LoadImage(fileContents);
              //if you need sprite for SpriteRenderer or Image
              Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f,texture.width, 
              texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
              Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
          }
      });
  ```
- `storage_url`:  Found in firebase->storage section. will be something like `gs://project_name.appspot.com/`
- `resource_name` : Name of a resource like `image_name.png`